# Adding waypoints on mobile app which uses Google Maps API 3.0

Tags: iphone, android, google-maps, directions

I am working on the app for Android and iOS platforms. My client requires that the app has to have "add directions" functionality.
Let's say I have a TO and FROM points set on my app, and I want to show the best route between these two points. If it's just these two points it's fine. There's plenty of resources on how to proceed. But if I want to add some extra directions, like GO THROUGH for example, the internet has no answers for me.
If you could point me to any apps (have to use Google Maps) for mobile platforms, where this functionality is working it would be great. Maybe you have some sort of documentation or some other materials on the subject.

Thanks, Mike (poland)

Comment: I'm wondering how you get the direction for only a start and end point as the Google Api doesn't provide a function to get the direction from point A to B.

Comment: @Flo Of course it does. Check google maps for Android and iOS :)

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the Google Maps API, I thought you were talking about the Google Android API. Sorry, my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to format the uri like:
from:50.74,14.00889+to:51.66444,17.85679+to:52.66444,17.85679
you can add as much +to terms as you want

edit:
if you ar using the Map api, you supposed to have a code like thisone to calculate a route:

```
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=de");
    urlString.append("&saddr=");//from
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)src.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)src.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
    urlString.append("&daddr=");//to
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
    urlString.append("&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml");
```

you should be able to add some waypoints in the discribed format.

```
        urlString.append("+to:")
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)waypoint.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)waypoint.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. But this is not really what I am looking for. Let's say I have an app on my Android. I want to look for a route between two points, and on the way I want to stop at a restaurant, so I include the address as "Go through" input field, much like "add direction" on fully featured pc/mac version of Google Maps. What I'm looking for is confirmation, that I can add this kind off functionality on mobile devices (Android 2.1, iOS 3.0).

Comment: with the string above you can write such a app, but i don't think that you are able to add such function in a existing app *confused*

Comment: It'll be a new app we are building. Thanks again. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

The google maps api v3 has a directions rederer. You can render a pollyline between two points and have the pollyline be dragable i.e. you can pick a pint along the route and reposition it as a 
waypoint. see the api documentation.

alternativly you can capture click events on the map add push the location into an array of stopovers to pass on the the routing request.